# custom picker editor with a grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Using EXTJS4, I have created a custom grid.  I would like one column to be editable using a picker.  If I wanted to do this with a editable text field, I would simply define the row as:

```
{dataIndex: 'ValueScore', width: 40 text:'Value',
                        field: {xtype: 'textfield'}}
```

So I think I should be able to do it like this:

```
{dataIndex: 'ValueScore', width: 40, text:'Value',
                        field: {xtype: 'pickerfield'}}
```

But how do I define my picker fields, etc?  Is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to sha who pointed me in the right direction on this.  First of all, turns out I wanted a Combobox (single select), not a picker.  But regardless, what did not understand (and could not find the doc for) was that EXT-JS will create these selection objects for you (like a combobox), and so you just need to pass the creation parameters in the "field" parameter.  For example:

```
{dataIndex: 'ValueScore', width: 40, text:'Value',
    field: {xtype: 'combobox', store: myStore, queryMode: 'local', displayField: 'value', valueField: 'value'}
```

Here I have pre-defined a data store called myStore that has a limited set of values I'd like the user to choose from.

Comment: Glad you figured this out. The fact that you don't create some of your elements directly, but just have to specify xtype and ExtJs will do the rest for you is kind of very basic ExtJs concept :) It's used everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Look how `Combobox`, `Date` and `Time` fields are inherited from `Picker` class and do something similar.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox

Comment: Ok, so I create a picker object to use for the column.  But how do I specify to use that particular picker in the declaration above?  xtype is "pickerfield", but how do I specify the object (and more to the point where are the options documented?  Thanks!!!

Comment: You use your own xtype. Whatever you declared in your custom class

Comment: The Date and Time examples specifically show an example creating a Ext.form.panel, but that example is not there for both for Picker and ComboBox.  How do I hook the panel and the picker together?